# Variables inside clean() method aren't saved in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

In models.py I have a model with custom `clean()` method. However, any variables I save in it aren't stored. If I try to save the variable outside of the `clean()` method, everything works well.

```
class MenuItem(SortableMixin):
item_internal = models.ForeignKey(Page, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
item_external = models.CharField(max_length=500000, blank=True, null=True)

def clean(self):
    if self.item_external is not None and self.item_internal is not None:
        raise ValidationError('Error')
    elif self.item_external is None and self.item_internal is None:
        raise ValidationError('Error')
    else:
        if self.item_external is not None:
            self.item_link = self.item_external
        elif self.item_internal is not None:
            self.item_link = '/' + self.item_internal.title_text.replace(' ', '%20')
```

Anything inside `item_link` is not saved. Why? How to fix it?

Comment: `clear` or `clean`?

Comment: Furthermore there is a syntax error in your code sample: you forgot to end the string in the second `Error`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem `clean`. My fault.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem My fault as well... It is just in the sample. I have it right in the real code.

Comment: Probably I'm missing something, but in your sample model, the `item_link` is not defined as a field.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem You are right. I save it as a string. Could that be the problem?

Comment: well if there is no (database) field, then this is just an attribute on an object, and it is lost when you save it to the database.

Comment: But what does "save it as a string" mean? Where are you expecting that to be stored?

Comment: I see. So it is not saved in to the database. How do I save it then?

Comment: @VítekPeterka: well you can construct a field, for example `item_link = fields.CharField(max_length=50000)` in the `class`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yep, that works. Maybe post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to save something into the database without creating a database field for it. The solution is simple:

```
item_link = fields.CharField(max_length=50000)
```

All I needed to do is to add that line to the `class`. Big thanks to Willem Van Onsem who helped me with this in the comments. Thanks!